# how to sort an Array of Dictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I need to sort an array of dictionaries, using a keyed object from the dictionary. The object is an NSString that contains a float. I used an NSSortDescriptor but it sorts alphabetically. How would I make a custom selector or comparator to do it numerically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you an idea of how this can be done using NSComparator blocks:

```
[array sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(id obj1, id obj2){
    double firstValue = [[obj1 objectForKey:@"someKey"] doubleValue];
    double secondValue = [[obj2 objectForKey:@"someKey"] doubleValue];
    double valueDiff = firstValue - secondValue;
    return (valueDiff == 0) ? NSOrderedSame : (valueDiff < 0) ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

`obj1` and `obj2` are id pointers to a pair of dictionary objects in your array.
Whatever you do within the NSComparator block is up to you. As long as you return either `NSOrderedSame`, `NSOrderedAscending` or `NSOrderedDescending`.

In general you might be better advised using a real numeric data type (à la `[NSNumber numberWith...:x]`) to hold such floating point values, than a string.

Comment: thanks for the help. This worked perfectly. I'm thinking about re-writting my app to change the NSString to NSNumbers. I didn't really want to do this but I guess it would be better in the long run. It's better to do it right before I release it, than to try and fix it after it has been release to the public.